# Jhipster e2e test failed

Tags: jhipster

I am trying jhipster so please bear my junior question.
When i try to launch end to end tests, i get this error, whitout any explicit message :

```
➜  store git:(master) ./gradlew npm_run_e2e 

> Task :npm_run_e2e FAILED

> store@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT e2e /Users/lbkpc/lab/projets-perso/e-commerce-app/store
> protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js

[20:09:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:09:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[20:09:05] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[20:09:05] E/launcher - Error: Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:540:9)
    at exec (/Users/lbkpc/lab/projets-perso/e-commerce-app/store/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:116:27)
    at /Users/lbkpc/lab/projets-perso/e-commerce-app/store/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:219:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[20:09:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! store@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT e2e: `protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the store@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lbkpc/.npm/_logs/2021-02-24T19_09_05_729Z-debug.log

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':npm_run_e2e'.
> Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 100

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Env :
jhipster : 6.10.5
node : v12.14.0
npm : 6.13.4
macOs catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade `webdriver-manager` to v12.1.8 or above in your `package.json`.

This was reported and fixed in JHipster v7.0.0-beta.1 ([issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13443)).